# CSS drop-down transition doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I want to make a drop-down menu transition, but it doesn't work at all. Other transitions work just fine but this one is really stubborn. What exactly am I doing wrong ?

In this example, the drop-down does not transition when it is shown:

```css
a {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li {
  height: 20px;
  padding-top: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #FFF;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: #4CA0DB;
}
li:hover {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  background-color: #4CA0DB;
}
.carret {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 5px;
  bottom: 1px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
/*this is where it breaks*/

.menu-hover ul li {
  display: none;
}
.menu-hover:hover ul li {
  background-color: #4CA0DB;
  display: block;
}
.menu-hover ul {
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="menu-hover"><a href="#">ABOUT THE UNIVERSITY<span class="carret">&#9660;</span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li>
          <a href="#"></a>За нас</li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"></a>Професии</li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"></a>Планове</li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"></a>Специалности</li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"></a>Преподаватели</li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"></a>Финансиране</li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"></a>Кандидатстване</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please post it on http://jsfiddle.net/ and share the link in order to help the other users to test your code.

Comment: Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/kjr3q4sg/1/

Comment: With which browser(s) are you testing?

Comment: @ochi : I think the problem is that the sub-menu appears without transition (the main links have a transition on `:hover`).

Comment: you cannot transition `display`, it is a discrete value from `none` to `block`.

Comment: Doesn't look okay in chrome for me; the ul and its lis render immediately instead of transitioning in.  I thought it might have to do with the display: none, changing this (removing or changing to visibility instead of display) doesn't help the issue (at least in chrome).

Comment: Doesn't work with opacity either.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it working by using visibility: hidden and visibility: visible instead of display: none and display: block. Thanks for the help! This is how it looks now:

```
.menu-hover ul li {
display: block;
visibility: hidden;
}

.menu-hover:hover ul li {
background-color: #4CA0DB;
visibility: visible;
transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

Comment: I had something similar by combining visibility and opacity, but where the elements overlapped could be seen because of the difference in the type of fade in.

Comment: [Here is a handy list of properties that can/can't be animated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties). However, now when your pointer is passed underneath the menu, the dropdown is activated. To prevent this, use [the `pointer-events: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) property: `.menu-hover ul { pointer-events: none; }` then apply pointer events to the children with: `.menu-hover:hover ul li { pointer-events: auto; }` [Works in all modern browsers and IE11](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events)